# can anyone please explain this bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

```
'while [ "$1" != "" ]
   do
    case "$1" in
            -a) AUTO=1; shift;;
            -A) AUTO=1; AUTOIGNORE=1; shift;;
            -E) EXCLUDE=$2; shift 2;;
            -o) NOAUTOIGNORE=1; shift;;
            --help) print_help; exit $STATE_OK;;
            -h) print_help; exit $STATE_OK;;
            -m) MTAB=$2; shift 2;;
            -f) FSTAB=$2; shift 2;;
            -N) FSF=$2; shift 2;;
            -M) MF=$2; shift 2;;
            -O) OF=$2; shift 2;;
            -T) TIME_TILL_STALE=$2; shift 2;;
            -i) IGNOREFSTAB=1; shift;;
            -w) WRITETEST=1; shift;;
            -L) LINKOK=1; shift;;
            -e) DFARGS=$2; shift 2;; 
            /*) MPS="${MPS} $1"; shift;;
            *) usage; exit $STATE_UNKNOWN;;
    esac'
```

Can anyone please explain what is this while loop do? what do these variables signify and what does shift here mean?

Comment: Format your code. I'd recommend reading the ABS Guide here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: It's reading the arguments passed to the script one by one and assigns the corresponding variables. Shift is shifting the arguments position : http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html

Comment: `what do these variables signify` - we would need to know the context to know that.

Comment: Looks like a string(!) containing some code that does a poor job of parsing command line options into _upper-case_ variables without allowing grouping of options but open to undefied behaviour if arguments contain ‘funny’ characters. Run it and the shell will probably tell you that there’s no such command. Or run the _contents of the string_ and expect failures.

Comment: @KamilCuk https://github.com/echocat/nagios-plugin-check_mountpoints/blob/master/check_mountpoints.sh    Checks_mountpoints  on the server

Comment: AUTO=0
AUTOIGNORE=0
IGNOREFSTAB=0
WRITETEST=0
NOAUTOCOND=1
NOAUTOIGNORE=0
DFARGS='' "
EXCLUDE=none                                                                                                               What does DFARGS with " " mean?

Comment: **We have a script that checks the mount points on the server.** 
 **THis part :**
#check if it stales

    ' df -k ${MP} &>/dev/null &
    
    DFPID=$!
    for (( i=1 ; i<$TIME_TILL_STALE ; i++ )) ; do
        if ps -p $DFPID > /dev/null ; then
            sleep 1
        else
            break
        fi
    done
    if ps -p $DFPID > /dev/null ; then
        $(kill -s SIGTERM $DFPID &>/dev/null)
        ERR_MESG[${#ERR_MESG[*]}]="${MP} did not respond in $TIME_TILL_STALE sec. Seems to be stale.

Comment: But  we are getting error is in this part of the code   ' df -k ${MP} &>/dev/null & ' I found the similar code on the internet : https://github.com/echocat/nagios-plugin-check_mountpoints/blob/master/check_mountpoints.sh  .The only difference I found here is there is a variable ${DFARGS} .Can anyone please explain what is this code df -k ..... doing and adding DFARGS would make what difference?

Comment: Then [you know the context and meaning of variables](https://github.com/echocat/nagios-plugin-check_mountpoints/blob/master/check_mountpoints.sh#L178). What exactly you don't understand? `Seems to be stale.` `But we are getting error` - Please create full, self-contained, well explained question. If you have an error, please then create _another_ full question specifically about that error. You asked about explanation of specified snippet of code - two answer you got are specifically about that code snippet.

Comment: `Can anyone please explain what is this code df -k` - in most trivial cases https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=df+-k+%24%7BDFARGS%7D+%24%7BMP%7D+%26%3E%2Fdev%2Fnull+%26 is just enough.

Comment: I  know that df is used to check the mount points but what does '-k' here do ? and what is ${DFARGS} doing ?.....New to bash shell script...

Answer (score 0):

Execute the Script in DEBUG mode .
example : ./bash -x NameOFScript.sh    or  ./bash -x NameOFScript.sh  Argument  ...

The Code snip shown , WHILE loop  ,  CASE statement  usage is there.

[Case Statement in a while loop, shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399306/case-statement-in-a-while-loop-shell-scripting)

Comment: SHIFT BUILT IN    Link   http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html

Answer (score -1):

This fragment of code analyzes the arguments passed to the script, and sets some variables. Argument are contained in variables like $1 $2 and so on.

Using a cycle, all the argument are scanned. Inside the cycle, only $1 is checked (via the case command) and then the "shift" command shifts the arguments, dropping the first ($1). After a shift, the previous $1 is lost, and the new $1 contains what the previous $2 was containing.

Note that some argument, like "-E", has to be followed by another one argument; in that case, if "-E" is detected as $1, then $2 is also used and one more shift is done.

Probably this fragment would be more concise by appending a shift at the end of the cycle, and deleting many specified on each single case.